# Vuex mapState reference error when vuex.js is included via script tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm running some test code for Vue.js and include Vue.js, Vuex and the javascript files via script tags (because it is for testing purposes only I don't want to use a build tool).

Most of the code runs correctly but the Vuex map functions (mapState, mapGetters ...) won't work. I always get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: mapState`. Why can't I access the mapState? Aren't that global functions when included via script tag?

Just an example using code from the vue docs:

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <title></title>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="app"></div>


    <!-- Libraries ---------- -->
    <script src="vendor/js/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="vendor/js/vuex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="app/js/store.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

store.js

```
const state = {
    count: 0
}


const getters = {
    evenOrOdd: state => state.count % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'
}


const mutations = {
    increment (state) {
        state.count++
    },
    decrement (state) {
        state.count--
    }
}


const actions = {
    increment: ({ commit }) => commit('increment'),
    decrement: ({ commit }) => commit('decrement'),
    incrementIfOdd: ({ commit, state }) => {
        if ((state.count + 1) % 2 === 0) {
            commit('increment')
        }
    },
    incrementAsync: ({ commit }) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                commit('increment')
                resolve()
            }, 1000)
        })
    }
}


const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
})
```

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <main>
            <h1 class="title">Heading</h1>
        </main>
    `,
    store,
    computed: {
        ...mapState([count])
    }
});
```

Comment: Include unless your code.

Comment: If you are including Vuex as a script rather than building, you will need to access mapState via Vuex as `Vuex.mapState`.

Comment: This got me one step further. Using `computed: Vuex.mapState({count: "count"})` works but `computed: { ...Vuex.mapState({count: "count"}) }` gives me an `Syntax Error: Unexpected token '...'. Expected a property name.` error. What's the problem with using the spread operator here because I will need it to merge the states with my own computed properties.

Comment: Object spread (`...mapState`) is not widely available in browsers at this time. You'll have to do it the old fashioned way.

Comment: You were right. The browser has support for array spreading but not for object spreading. Is there a simple 'old fashioned way'? I think the fact that all local computed properties are functions inside the computed object an not just key:value pairs will make it difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Many code examples I see

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
```

used to allow mapState to be referenced.

But as you say, you are including Vue and Vuex by referencing their scripts instead of using a build system

```
<script src="vendor/js/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vendor/js/vuex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in this case, directly using "Vuex" as below works:

```
Vuex.mapState
```